# slidetoggle multiple divs with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a table of information for artists. Fields are generated dynamically from database. If any user clicks on artist name, few others information related to the artist shows down. At first rest of the information are kept hide.

```
<!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title></title>
</head>

<body>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>Artist Name</td>
    <td>Birth Year</td>
    <td>Age</td>
</tr>
<tr id="collapsible">
    <td><h2><a href="" id="check-details">A</a></h2></td>
    <td>1988</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <div id="rest">
        <tr>
            <td>Blah</td>
            <td>Blah</td>
            <td>Blah</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</tr>
<tr id="collapsible">
    <td><h2><a href="" id="check-details">B</a><h2></td>
    <td>1988</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <div id="rest">
        <tr>
            <td>Blah</td>
            <td>Blah</td>
            <td>Blah</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</tr>
<tr id="collapsible">
    <td><h2><a href="" id="check-details">C</a><h2></td>
    <td>1988</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <div id="rest">
        <tr>
            <td>Blah</td>
            <td>Blah</td>
            <td>Blah</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
  </tr>
  </table>

  </body>

  </html>
```

**Jquery**

```
            $(document).ready(function(){

    // hide all div containers
    $('collapsible#rest').hide();
    // append click event to the a element
    $('#check-details').click(function(e) {
        // slide down the corresponding div if hidden, or slide up if shown
        $(this).parent().next('#rest').slideToggle('slow');
        // set the current item as active
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
   });
```

Comment: Don't use multiple `id's` . `Id's` are unique use `class` instead .

Comment: ID of an eleemnt must be unique.... use classes to group elements together

Comment: i have changed id named to class names but yet no luck

Comment: You are loading commom `jquery` file?

Comment: No, right now individual file. But i intend to use it on my main work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had quite a few errors there.
 For example, you can't have random div's inside table rows unless they are inside  elements.
 I corrected the syntax and made some improvements to your javascript code.
(`$(this).parents('.collapsible').next('.rest').slideToggle('slow');`)
 jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q6AmR/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent()
```

Is incorrect, your a tag is in a h2 which is it's parent, you'd have to do

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent()
```

To get back to the tr which contains the div.

Also, having a div within a tr is poorly formed HTML, as if having a tr within a tr.

I would recommend changing the HTML to something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="" class="artistLink">Katy Perry</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rest">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $("tr.rest").hide();

    $("a.artistLink").click(function(e) {
        $(this).parent().parent().next("tr.rest").slideToggle();
        ...
    });
</script>
```

This was written on my iPad so might need tweaking!